# Cannot set multibinding because multivalue converter must be specified wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Ok, I have got into below way after following these 2 posts [**[`Post 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510196/multibinding-generates-cannot-set-multibinding-because-multivalueconverter-must)**, **[`Post 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424364/cannot-set-multibinding-because-multivalueconverter-must-be-specified-wpf)**] regarding the question. But this issue is blowing my heads out even after following right ways of implemeting.

So here is my converter which is added in `ViewModels` directory of project:

```
public class ChangePasswordConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ....
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now below is my `HomeWindow.xaml`

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="KEOffice.Views.HomeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:KEOffice.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KEOffice.ViewModels"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ChangePasswordConverter x:Key="ChangePasswordConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <!--But when I try to do this-->
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangePassword.UpdatePassword}">
           <Button.CommandParameter>
               <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="{StaticResource ChangePasswordConverter}">
                   <Binding Path="OldPass" ElementName="OldPass"/>
                   <Binding Path="NewPass" ElementName="NewPass"/>
                   <Binding Path="ConfirmPass" ElementName="ConfirmPass"/>
               </MultiBinding>
          </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Even though I have given proper reference to `viewmodels`, where converter exists and Specified valid `StaticResource` it throws `Cannot set multibinding because multivalue converter must be specified`. I have also done rebuild, clean-rebuild etc., but still the same issue. What else I need to take care to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use ConverterParameter to specify the converter, you use Converter.

Comment: Shit man.. That one Attribute.. :( Thanks for the quick answer... :)